# How to know if a TextView or ImageView have been seen by user in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a chatting app like WhatsApp. Now I dont understand how WhatsApp knows a TextView or ImageView have been seen by user in RecyclerView. Is there a default function to these view or do i have to create it?

Comment: There is no default function . You need to check the items visible on screen inside `RecyclerView`. Usually u can mark all previous message read if user is on latest message but that's upto you .

Comment: you can just hit api or socket when ever user open its chat screen with two user thats mean user she the message

Comment: ok i will search into that

Comment: try to add index variable in your adapter and assign this variable to the index of shown items in the recycler view and pass this index variable to your fragment or activity through viewModels then if the index in view model == to index inside your adapter make helper function to set this image or text to seen or anything you want, idk if this is efficient but you can try.